# How do you change the background color of the electron browserWindow (e.g. with a button click)?

Tags: colors, background, electron

I know how to change the background colors in the CSS, but there is still the slightest border in the electron window (frameless), and I want to change that to the same color as in my webpage.

The window is generated in the

`app.on('ready', function() {});`

And I don't know how to call that again, and change the attribute for the backgroundColor.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can set it when you create your windows, did you tried that?

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval Yes, I know that's how I can do it one way, but what I'm trying to do is change the background color after the window is created, through the use of a button click on the window or an element displayed on the window.

Comment: uhmm, i've checked that on the docs and didn't find another way to set a background. maybe you can do it dinamically and relaunch your app in every change of color

Answer (score 0):

You could use `BrowserWindow`'s `backgroundColor` property.

But since you want to change the background color *after* the window's loaded, what you can do is, change the `body` element's `background-color` attribute in your Javascript event handler.

Code snippet (without Electron but should work the same):

```js
function clickHandler() {
  $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="clickHandler()" value="Click me!" />
```